# AWS EC2 security group source

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, firewall

I'm currently trying to configure a security group and allow MS SQL connections from my other instance. I want to be able to specify the security group's name as the source.

But the connection is not going through. The instance's firewall has a rule to allow connections on the port. In fact, if I specify the IP of the machine as the source, it works. Just not the security group name.

There are two other rules for the same port and they're for specific IPs only.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you doing port 1433?

Comment: yes, i'm on port 1433

Answer (score 0):

Use the other instance's private IP address (10.X.X.X) to make the connection when the security group ID is used as the source. This does not apply between regions and probably not between availability zones.